# bash: webpack: command not found

Tags: npm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwF3H.png)

When the webpack is downloaded, the prompt has been installed, but the use of instructions can't be used. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Use this command: `npx webpack`. The `npx` command runs binaries that are in your project's `node_modules` folder. Assuming you've already done `npm install webpack` or equivalent, this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install webpack-cli. For that run:
`npm install webpack-cli -g`

Then you can run `webpack -v` in command line.

Comment: Through the instructions you gave me, I tried, but I still couldn't solve it. I made a lot of mistakes. The front is NPM WARN deprecated nomnom@1.8.1: Package no longer supported. Contact support@n pmjs.com support@n.

NPM WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1: Thanks for using Babel: we re commend, we, and it's all behind a bunch of random codes. I won't issue it.

Comment: WARN shouldn't break your installation prosses. What is the error?

Comment: @Mr.lu if you have solved the problem, you should post an answer to the question. I'm having the same issue, and it would be nice to know how to resolve it.

Comment: There's no reason it install Webpack globally. You need Webpack and the rest of your dependencies in order to run Webpack successfully, so install your project's dependencies and you'll have a local copy of Webpack in your project's `node_modules` directory.

Answer (score -1):

I see it has been a while since asking this question, however, I will share my experience.
Installing webpack globally makes it available from terminal. On the opposite, in case you have installed it locally, the webpack command is not available, but you can use npm script.

You can find more detailed explanation [here](https://medium.com/a-beginners-guide-for-webpack-2/installing-webpack-b2edf9943509)

Hope this is helpful for everyone :)

Comment: Per the webpack docs, this is *not* the recommended practice, as it version locks you, which could cause problems with deploys to other environments.

Comment: Right. Install it locally, like any other dependency, and run `npx webpack`. This is straightforward, unless you start confusing things by installing global copies of it.